# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, .net, argumentnullexception

I know this has been asked before, but I don't fully understand the answers given as I'm very new to programming.

I've tried adding a null check before the line of code, however, I'm not sure what to do with a "Directory" once it's been checked, if that makes any sense?

```
    public class Config
{
    public Config()
    {
        _random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);


        _dir = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
               AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath,
               "TradeAgent",
               "Configs");

        if (!Directory.Exists(_dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(_dir);
        }
    }
```

The error is being thrown on the "_dir = Path.Combine" line.

Can someone break this down for me like I'm 5?

**EDIT:  I just noticed below this a bit it says:**

```
private string _dir = null;
```

No idea how to fix this, but maybe that's the problem?

**EDIT2:  When changing private string _dir = null; to something else like "abc" instead of "null", I no longer get the nullpoint error, although obviously I get a new error saying "the name abc does not exist in the current context".**

Again, I don't know how to fix this, but it does seem that _dir is the problem.

Comment: For what purpose you are using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath` this may be `null` in your case obviously that cause the error

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea.  This is an old open source project that I've been trying to fix as it hasn't been updated in some time.  As of right now I've got it running, it just throws the null exception error while trying to use it.  What exactly does Appdomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath do?

Comment: Do you have any idea about in which directory you want to create the `Configs`

Comment: Yes.  Could this be a permissions problem possibly?